# remove the duplicates in an array of object

Tags: ruby

How to remove the duplicate objects in an array of objects. 
for ex:

```
 [#< @a:1, @b:2>, #< @a:3, @b:3>, #<@a:3, @b:3>] => [ #< @a:1, @b:2>, #< @a:3, @b:3>].
```

Also my understanding is no two objects can be same..correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: It's hard to know what you're asking here. Try to produce an example that's small enough we can run and understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" along with the linked pages, and "[mcve]". When asking we need to see more than just a syntactically incorrect definition of an array. We also need to see what you tried and an explanation of why it didn't work. Currently it looks like you didn't try and you are asking us to write the code for you, so the evidence of effort is important. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#uniq`, but you'll need to make a small change to your class. Per [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq), `uniq` "compares values using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency," so you'll need to define `hash` and `eql?` such that they will identify two objects of your class as duplicates. For example, if two objects with the same `a` and `b` attributes are duplicates, you might do this:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :a, :b

  def initialize(a, b)
    @a, @b = a, b
  end

  def hash
    [ a, b ].hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    hash == other.hash
  end
end

arr = [ Foo.new(1, 2), Foo.new(3, 3), Foo.new(3, 3) ]
p arr.uniq
# => [#<Foo:0x007f686ac36700 @a=1, @b=2>, #<Foo:0x007f686ac366b0 @a=3, @b=3>]
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to or can't define `hash` and `eql?` methods you can use the block form of `uniq`:

```
class Bar
  attr_reader :a, :b

  def initialize(a, b)
    @a, @b = a, b
  end
end

arr2 = [ Bar.new(1, 2), Bar.new(3, 3), Foo.new(3, 3) ]

p arr2.uniq {|obj| [ obj.a, obj.b ] }
# => [#<Bar:0x007fe80f7b6750 @a=1, @b=2>, #<Bar:0x007fe80f7b6700 @a=3, @b=3>]
```

You can see [both of these](https://repl.it/FmZL/1) on repl.it.

Comment: You might mention that  `arr.uniq #=> arr` if `Foo#eql?` or `Foo#hash` is not defined, In that case [Object#eql?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) and/or [Object#hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) are used by `uniq`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq). Example from the docs:

```
a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
a.uniq 
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Note that this method uses their `hash` or `eql?` methods to identify duplicates. That said: If `uniq` doesn't work like expected, then you probably make sure that `hash` or `eql?` are implemented appropriately.